# Why functions have priority over the Property-like callables in the same scope?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I just noticed something interesting when testing a code and I would like more explanation.
Why functions have the priority over lambdas when they are in the same scope ?

For example :

```
fun sum(x: Int, y:Int) = x + y
val sum = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }
// here, the compiler use the fonction (first line) and not the lambda
println(sum(1, 2))
```

In this case, I use `invoke()` to call the lambda instead of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ***`Overload` resolution*** section of [kotlin language specification](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#overload-resolution) does touch on this, it states

> When calculating overload candidate sets, member callables produce the
>   following separate sets (***ordered by higher priority first***):
>
> ```
> Member function-like callables;
> Member property-like callables.
> ```

but the specification still seems to be a work in progress as it contains a lot of TODO's, one specific TODO that would be relevant to your question is in the ***Callable references*** section

> TODO(We might get new ambiguity between props and funs with the same
>   name)

So it seems to get a definite answer, you will have to wait until the language specification matures.